# Assembly runtime error when jumping to parent label?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I dabbled with Assembly (NASM flavor) a bit a while back and I'm trying to learn it again. (I know I can count the string length first, but it's an excercise)

Anyways, I wrote this code to print out a null terminated string to `stdout` using `sys_write`. (I plan to generalize it, I'm just testing right now.)

It seems like it will work because if I increment `i` before calling `sys_write` then it prints `'e'`, but if I increment it afterwards, then it prints `'H'` as expected. However, as soon as it encounters: `jne print_loop`, it produces a run-time error with the error code of `-1`. I tried several jump instructions and they all crash, but as soon as I remove the jump the program runs without any errors.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/4qXx6y#view_edit_box)

```
SECTION .data
    hello:
        db "Hello World!/n",0

SECTION .bss
    i: 
        resb 1

SECTION .text
    global _start

    _start:
        mov ecx, hello
        call print

        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h

    print:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov edx, 1

        print_loop:
            push eax
            mov eax, [i]
            lea ecx, [ecx+eax]
            pop eax

            int 80h
            inc dword [i]
            cmp ecx, 0  
            jne print_loop ; if I comment this out, it runs without error.

        ret
```

Here is the fixed version:

```
%macro print_ 1
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, %1

    call print
%endmacro

%macro exit_ 1
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, %1
    int 80h
%endmacro

SECTION .data
    hello:
        db "Hello World!/n",0

SECTION .bss
    i: 
        resb 1

SECTION .text
    global _start

    _start:
        print_ hello
        exit_ 0

    ;print code called by print_ macro
    print:
        push ecx
        count:
            inc ecx
            cmp byte [ecx], 0
            jne count

        mov edx, ecx
        pop ecx
        sub edx, ecx

        int 80h
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code:

```
i: 
    resb 1
```

Here you reserve space for one byte, but in the print function you treat `i` as a dword.

```
int 80h
```

This will trash the old value of `eax`, since `eax` holds the return value of the syscall. So you need to reload `eax` with the syscall number (4) at each iteration.

```
lea ecx, [ecx+eax]
```

Here you overwrite the base address of the string with `&string[i]`, which will result in incorrect addresses on subsequent iterations since you don't preserve the original `ecx` value.

```
cmp ecx, 0
```

I'm not sure why you expect `ecx` to be 0. It would make more sense to load the byte stored at `[ecx]` and compare *that* against zero (before the syscall).

Comment: In the original code I had planned to use sys_write one byte at a time, it was to be zero after incrementing over the whole string. Also note that `lea ecx, [hello+eax]` was the original. Sorry for the rush, I have to leave.

Comment: My point about comparing `ecx` to 0 was that it doesn't make sense to compare the _address_ against zero to find the end of a string. It's the value _stored at that address_ that should be compared against 0.

Comment: Well here was my plan, I would make `ecx` the pointer to the first letter by assigning it `hello`. Then I would assign it ecx+1 every time to increment it, I was using eax because I don't really know what format it wants the offset in.

I didn't know int 80h clobbered the registers though, I assumed it backed them up to the stack beforehand.

Comment: Also, it was probably just a typo where I meant to put cmp [ecx], 0.

As the other answerer pointed out, I shouldn't be asking questions here just because I don't have access to the resources to do it myself. 

The biggest difficulty of Assembly is knowing all the nooks and crannies.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems.

First:

```
  mov eax, [i]
```

`i` is a byte variable, but the instruction reads 4 bytes from its location.

```
  inc dword [i]
```

`i` is a byte variable, but the instruction increments a 4-byte value at its location.

Second (I think):

What is going to be in `ecx` after this instruction

```
  lea ecx, [ecx+eax]
```

executes the 2nd time? Is it still going to be a valid address pointing into `hello`?

And btw, learn to use the debugger. It's about the time.

Comment: I know perfectly well how to use a debugger, but I am doing this entirely on Ideone.com. I am at school and do not have access to a Linux machine. 

Also, `lea ecx, [ecx+eax]` was not the original function, it used to be `lea ecx, [hello+eax]` and I changed it without any seemingly side effects. It still crashed with `lea ecx, [hello+eax]`

I put `inc dword [i]` because I was unsure if it mattered, since it would only touch the lowest byte anyways.

Comment: So, just because you don't have access to a machine with a debugger, you want us to debug your stuff for you? And it's urgent, I suppose?

Comment: Btw, even if value-wise only one byte is modified, the CPU checks that it can access the entire `dword`. So, you shouldn't do that sort of thing unless running a risk of crashing is OK with you.

Comment: Sorry for being short, I was rushed. You're completely right, I was impatient. Anyways, in `lea ecx, [ecx+eax]` `eax` was supposed to be one. I was using `eax` because I didn't know what exactly the offset had to be in terms of storage type. I was expecting it to load `ecx+1` into `ecx` and then it would  load `ecx+1+1` (where the first +1 was the result of the previous operation)

I'm not really sure what I was doing.

Thanks for the help.